# Removing Outliers in a Multi-feature Regression Problem

Tags: python, regression

I have a regression problem having 1 target and 10 features. When I look at the outliers for each feature by box-plot, they have different number of outliers. While removing outliers, do I need to also remove the associated target values with those outliers?

I mean, let's say: for #1 feature I have 12 outliers and I removed them with 12 target values. Then, for #2 feature I have 23 outliers and I removed them with 23 target values, as well, and so on. The procedure would be like this, or how should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine each row of your data contains an ID, the value of the target and 10 feature values, one of each feature. **To answer our question**: if you want to remove the outliers, you have to **remove the whole observation/row** - the value that you classify as an outlier, the corresponding target value, as well as all other 9 corresponding feature values. So you would have to **filter each row for the entry of feature_i being smaller than the threshold_i** that you defined as an outlier.

The reason is that a multilinear regression calculates the influence of an incremental change in one feature on the target, assuming all other 9 features being constant. Removing a single feature value without removing the target and the other features of this observation simply does not work in such a model (assuming you are using an OLS).

However, I would be cautious with removing outliers. I don't know about your sample size and what you consider an outlier and it would help to know more about your research question, data and methodology.

Comment: Data size is 585. I'm trying Local Outlier Factor method right now, but I will check other methods for outliers. Actually, I've tried different regression models and now I'd like to see the effect of outlier removal on model performance..

Comment: Can I ask, when you are referring to outliers, you mean outliers in the features? I would've thought outliers are usually referring to the observations/responses. Wanna clarify the reason for removing feature outliers

Comment: Yeah, I mean outliers in the features after simply creating box-plots.